# Wait for Acrobat Reader to exit

Tags: vb.net

What I want to do: I'm writing a temporary pdf file from a database and call this file to open it in acrobat reader. And yes, the pdfs are safe, I made them by my own.

Now my problem is to delete the temporary file after acrobat reader is closed. This code works, but I think, it is not really the best pracise.

```
    Dim myp As New Process
    myp.StartInfo.FileName = filename
    myp.Start()
    myp.WaitForInputIdle()
    myp.WaitForExit()
    Dim errorfree As Boolean = False
    While errorfree = False
        Try
            Threading.Thread.Sleep(250)
            File.Delete(filename)
            errorfree = True
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
    End While
    myp.Dispose()
```

Info: for acrobat reader, the two lines

```
 myp.WaitForInputIdle()
 myp.WaitForExit()
```

are not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`Process.Exited`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.exited) event:

```
'creating the process.
Dim myp As New Process
myp.StartInfo.FileName = filename
myp.Start()

'bind the "Exited"-event to a sub.
myp.EnableRaisingEvents = True
AddHandler myp.Exited, AddressOf SubToDeleteFile

'the sub used by the "Exited"-event.
Public Sub SubToDeleteFile(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim errorfree As Boolean = False

    While errorfree = False
        Try
            Dim filename As String = DirectCast(sender, Process).StartInfo.FileName

            Threading.Thread.Sleep(250)
            File.Delete(filename)
            errorfree = True
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
    End While

    'dispose the process at the end.
    If sender IsNot Nothing AndAlso TypeOf sender Is Process Then
        DirectCast(sender, Process).Dispose()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This worked, thank you! I used a lamda expression instead of `AddressOf`. Perfect!

Comment: @muffi  You can and should dispose of the Process in the `Exited` handler. With a null check before calling `[Process].Dispose()`.

Comment: @Jimi thanks for your comment, of course you are right. In my question you can see that I dispose this object. And in the exit handler, of corse, too.

Comment: @muffi If you use the Exited event, of course, dispose of the Process in the handler only. Otherwise, you'll get an exception (yes, well, obviously :)